# Working with the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

For site wide specific JS code (i.e. for the header, which appears on all pages). Where should this be placed? In:

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

Is that right?

For pages#home. Which `root_url` also points to (`root :to => 'pages#home'`). Where should my JS file be placed in the pipeline?

```
app/assets/javascripts/pages/home.js
```

And regards to my `application.js`. Is this right? It currently looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory .
```

Or should I just embed page specific JS in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to put js code in application.js. You can put that code in any other file on the `assets/javascripts` folder and it will be included automatically by the `require_directory` or `require_tree` command. Your `application.js` file is perfectly fine as it is right now, but you might want to use `require_tree` instead of `require_directory` for recursive inclusion.

For example, the javascripts files in `app/assets/javascripts/pages` will be included by `require_tree` but not by `require_directory`.

Recommended reading: [Asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)